# Встраивание окна стороннего приложения в форму c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, winapi

Имеется 2 приложения:
1. Основное Unity приложение.
2. Интерфейс реализованный с помощью WinForms.
Интерфейс с помощью [аргументов командной строки](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) запускает Unity приложение и встраивает его окно внутри себя.
Пример кода встраивания с сайта  Unity приведен ниже:

```
namespace Container
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

    internal delegate int WindowEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, WindowEnumProc func, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private Process process;
    private IntPtr unityHWND = IntPtr.Zero;

    private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
    private readonly IntPtr WA_ACTIVE = new IntPtr(1);
    private readonly IntPtr WA_INACTIVE = new IntPtr(0);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "UnityGame.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-parentHWND " + panel1.Handle.ToInt32() + " " + Environment.CommandLine;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            process.Start();

            process.WaitForInputIdle();
            // Doesn't work for some reason ?!
            //unityHWND = process.MainWindowHandle;
            EnumChildWindows(panel1.Handle, WindowEnum, IntPtr.Zero);

            unityHWNDLabel.Text = "Unity HWND: 0x" + unityHWND.ToString("X8");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ".\nCheck if Container.exe is placed next to UnityGame.exe.");
        }

    }

    private void ActivateUnityWindow()
    {
        SendMessage(unityHWND, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private void DeactivateUnityWindow()
    {
        SendMessage(unityHWND, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_INACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private int WindowEnum(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam)
    {
        unityHWND = hwnd;
        ActivateUnityWindow();
        return 0;
    }

    private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveWindow(unityHWND, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);
        ActivateUnityWindow();
    }

    // Close Unity application
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            process.CloseMainWindow();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            while (!process.HasExited)
                process.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateUnityWindow();
    }

    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeactivateUnityWindow();
    }
  }
}
```

В примере настраивается и запускается новый процесс с нужными аргументами. Есть ли возможность встроить окно уже запущенного Unity приложения в форму без создания нового процесса?
Пытался использовать [SetParent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) функцию передав handle процесса, но как то безуспешно.

Comment: А как вы получаете handle уже запущенного процесса? Покажите код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Получал handle главного окна процесса и передавал его в SetParent `[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);`
        `SetParent(Process.GetProcessesByName("editorCore")[0].MainWindowHandle, this.panel1.Handle);`